# Importing CSV file to JTable

Tags: java, user-interface

Currently got a table displaying ID,location,status,patient of an app I'm making as a small project. I'm trying to import a CSV file (without using a CSV reader) onto this table but am having difficulty.

```
table = new JTable();
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
    new Object[][] {
    },
    new String[] {
        "ID", "Location", "Status", "Patient"
    }
));
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenCSV:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv")); 
List myEntries = reader.readAll();
JTable table = new JTable(myEntries.toArray());
```

Comment: that requires a package I want to do it without doing that

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static Object[][] readCsv(String file) throws IOException {
    List<Object[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
            lines.add(line.split(","));
    }
    return lines.toArray(new Object[lines.size()][]);
}
```

and

```
    JTable table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        readCsv("data/test.csv"),
        new String[] {
            "ID", "Location", "Status", "Patient"
        }
    ));
```

Comment: how do I enter the file ? do i put it as like String "example.csv"

Comment: Getting errors for some reason when I try this code